# MVC 4 : jQuery AutoComplete shows list of "undefined"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-autocomplete

I am new with MVC and now have problem. Please give me solution.

I am creating simple AutoComplete textbox in MVC4.
Here is my code

**In controler:**

```
public ActionResult List(string term)
    {
        DebateEntities  _db = new DebateEntities ();
        var results = from u in _db.Users 
                      where u.username.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())
                      select new { u.username};

        return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**In View**

```
@model DebateApp.Models.MessageModels 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >  
<head>  
    <title></title>  
    <link href="http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/jQueryCodeSamplesMVC/Content/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />  
</head>  
<body>  

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <fieldset>  
        <legend>User Lookup</legend>  
            @Html.TextBox("name")
            @Html.TextBox("userID")
            <input type="submit" value="Find" />          
        </fieldset>  
    }

</body>  
    <script src="http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/jQueryCodeSamplesMVC/Scripts/jQueryUI/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/jQueryCodeSamplesMVC/Scripts/jQueryUI/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#name").autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("List")',
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("#name").val(ui.item.username);
            }
        });  

</script>  
</html>
```

When i type the 'd' in textbox, a list appear, but they all "undefined".
When i choose a "undefined" option, it show correct username.

**How can i solve "undefined" list ?**

Thank you

Comment: Is the Action at Controller receiving some value in "term"?

Comment: have you tried setting a break point at `source: '@Url.Action("List")'` and verifying that your data is being serialized properly?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah even i faced this problem earlier. The main reason for it could be your jquery code couldnt extract contents from  source reference tags.

I suggest you to use the following

```
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"; type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"; type="text/javascript">
```

and for jquery something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
      $('#name').autocomplete({
          source: '@Url.Action("List")',
          minLength: 1,
          select: function (evt, ui) {
            }
      });
  });
 </script>
```

and you can use the same code for the controller. i can find no problem with it. Most probably you wont get the undefined any more.